# WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty in UWP

Tags: c#, storyboard, uwp

I'm new to Storyboard animation,

```
Storyboard storyBoard = new Storyboard();
foreach (var segment in this.PieSegmentCollection) 
{
    DoubleAnimation angleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { From = StartAngle, To = EndAngle, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.8)) };
    storyBoard.Children.Add(angleAnimation);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(angleAnimation, "PieSegment.EndAngleProperty");
    Storyboard.SetTarget(angleAnimation, segment);
}
storyboard.Begin();
```

I try to animate each segments in the PieSegmentCollection, but i got this error

> WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty
>   (PieSegment.ArcEndAngleProperty) on specified object.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The propery name is certainly `EndAngle`, so you should set the target property this way:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(angleAnimation, "EndAngle");
```

Comment: In WPF `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(angleAnimation, new PropertyPath(PieSegment.EndAngleProperty));` works fine.

Comment: UWP is not WPF.

Comment: Yes, i tried what you said in UWP but animation not working.

Comment: What exactly does "animation not working" mean. Do you still get the error message from your original question?

Comment: It means, error should be resolved but animation doesn't happens in visual. After that I set `EnableDependentAnimation` is `true` problem was solved. Thanks for your help.